# Multi Variable Limit check

Tags: calculus

I've just done my Calculus 2 test, and there is one question that I'm not quite sure about.

Question was: Calculate the limit, or prove it doesn't exist:
[image]

Some friends of mine said they calculated the limit and found it was 0.

But, I've been trying to prove that there is no limit.
I used y = x+1, and y = 2x+1.
So y goes to 1, just as the limit says, and it had gotten me 2 differents limits, and that's why there is no limit.

Hope my problem is clear. Can anyone please verify me that there is no limit in this specific question? It may help me get less nervous.

Thanks.

Comment: Your method of proving this is perfectly good. Indeed this function has no limit. In your first case, it goes to 1, in the other case it goes to 0.5, hence, by definition, the function has no limit here.